# Can I make a link that only works after several clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, onclick

I'm trying to put in a small easter egg on a site I'm building where if a user clicks a link x amount of times it will trigger a popup, I'd guess this would be some kind of JS or JQuery but I have no idea where to start or if it's even possible. I guess what I really want is something like the easter egg built into the Android 'About Phone' page, which opens a new page after about 7 clicks within 5 seconds. Is there any way to do this in a browser?

Maybe an OnClick command which adds 1 to a counter and does an action when the counter reaches a specified number, but resets the counter to 0 every 10 seconds? (I don't want to make it too easy to find!)

Thanks

Comment: So do it? You just described a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with jQuery:

Html:

```
<a id='lnkEgg' data-clicks='0'>Click for surprise</a>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#lnkEgg").on("click",function(){
        var c=$(this).data("click");
        if(c==7){
            //if it equals to whatever number you are chasing
            //open the popup
        }else{
            $(this).data("clicks",c++);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, definately got me moving in the right direction, sorry I can't upvote but I need to get more rep points first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a *setTimeout* (which you clear each time) and *preventDefault* on the click event if it doesn't meet your requirements.

```
(function (node) { // IIFE to keep our namespace clean :)
    var timer,
        count = 0;
    function timeup() {
        count = 0;
    }
    function handler(e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(timeup, 5e3); // 5 seconds
        ++count;
        if (count < 7) // number of clicks
            e.preventDefault();
    }
    node.addEventLister('click', handler);
}(document.getElementById('myLink'))); // passing the <a> into the IIFE
```

This code must be run **after** the target element exists

Answer (score 0):

@TheVillageIdiot's technique is the way to go. Here I'll just show some approach using the same technique:

```js
$(function(){
    var egg = $('#lnkEgg');
    egg.on('click', function() {
        //increment and check if magic clicks has been reached
        if( ++$(this).data().clicks == 7 ) {
            console.log( "You've now clicked the required number of times");
            //do some more operations
            $(this).data('complete', true);
            console.log( $(this).data() );
        };
    });
    //Reset counter every 10 seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        egg.data().clicks = 0;
    }, 10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="lnkEgg" data-clicks="0">Click for surprise</a>
```